# HTML5 Canvas, How to show animated attacks between two points

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I want to show attack animation between two points (source & target) on HTML5 canvas, similar to http://map.ipviking.com/

Below code making missile movement too slow at the end when distance remain short and does not seems real like a missile attack

```
velocityX = target.x - missile.shift.x;
velocityY = target.y - missile.shift.y;
missile.shift.x += velocityX * .001;
missile.shift.y += velocityY * .001;
```

Please help!

Comment: *does not seems real* That's a very subjective opinion. What do you mean by "real"? Is an object translating with a easeOutQuad easing real?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At row 1-2 you make the velocities depend on the distance between missile and target, shorter distance implies lower speed.

I guess what you seek is the direction, normalized, and then to choose the speed by yourself.

Let me show a simple example.

```
Target is at: [2, 3]
Missile is at: [4, 8]
```

Velocities (by your formula) are: [2, 5] (the diff on x and y separate)
The "normalizationFactor" is calculated by the "pythagoras formulae":

```
var normalizationFactor= Math.sqrt(2*2 + 5*5);
```

To normalize, you need to shorten both `velocityX` and `velocityY` by `normalizationFactor`.
After that, you can chose which number to like to choose your speed with. (you use 0.001 by now)

This is my attempt to patch your solution, haven't tested it, but you should get the idea:

```
velocityX = target.x - missile.shift.x;
velocityY = target.y - missile.shift.y;
var normalizationFactor= Math.sqrt(velocityX*velocityX + velocityY*velocityY);
var yourSpeed = 0.001;
missile.shift.x += yourSpeed * velocityX / normalizationFactor;
missile.shift.y += yourSpeed * velocityY / normalizationFactor;
```

Comment: If you are using a scalar (speed factor), then velocityX and Y would have to be a unit vector

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention that Derek, excactly!

Comment: Thanks Gustav & Derek, your solutions seems not working in my code something i'm doing wrong now missile not moving any ware. Can you make quick fiddle?

Comment: Use Chrome Dev Tools (or similar) to step through your code and see the values that the variables get.

Comment: See here is the data
{"missileStartX":403,"missileStartY":106,"TargetX":811,"TargetY":202}

But in loop i'm getting same values again and again.
normalizationFactor = 418.94391618846697 
shiftX = 403.31926100067335 
shiftY = 106.78277537866411

Comment: Gustav: i have created fiddle on your suggestion http://jsfiddle.net/atulkushwah/wg1seup6/1/ see here circle not moving if we added normalizationFactor. Please suggest!

Comment: Change speed to 1 instead of 0.03, you will see that it moves :)

Comment: Of course, your algorithm for collision to the wall is wrong. But that's another question :)